# Installation qtsampleplayer ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, qt, cmake

I'm new to Linux so please accept my apologies if the question is trivial. I'm trying to install `qtsampleplayer` under Ubuntu 14.04 (32bit) according to [these instructions](https://github.com/bitmovin/libdash):

Prerequisite: libdash must be built as described in the previous section.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qtmultimedia5-dev qtbase5-dev libqt5widgets5 libqt5core5 libqt5gui5 libqt5multimedia5 libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5opengl5 libav-tools libavcodec-dev libavdevice-dev libavfilter-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libpostproc-dev libswscale-dev
cd libdash/libdash/qtsampleplayer
mkdir build
cd build
wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.11.2-Linux-i386.sh
chmod a+x cmake-2.8.11.2-Linux-i386.sh
./cmake-2.8.11.2-Linux-i386.sh
./cmake-2.8.11.2-Linux-i386/bin/cmake ../
make
./qtsampleplayer
```

but unfortunately during step 11 (`./cmake-2.8.11.2-Linux-i386/bin/cmake ../`) I encountered an error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:27 (message): The imported target "Qt5::Gui" references the file "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so" but this file does not exist. Possible reasons include:

The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
The installation package was faulty and contained "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake"
```

Installation was successful but under 12.04. If anybody can help please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download the package

```
apt-get download libgl1-mesa-glx
```

navigate to your home folder using nautilus or thunar or your favorite file manager using the sudo command

```
sudo nautilus /home/
```

Right-click on the deb file and select extract. Navigate to the folder **libgl1-mesa-glx_10.0.0-1ubuntu2_i386 > usr > lib > x86_64-linux-gnu > mesa**

Now, rename the file **libGL.so.1.2.0** as **libGL.so**

Move, or copy and paste that file to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/

Comment: @Dave no problem . please accept the answer using the icon to the left to close out the question.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you need the OpenGL library. Searching for that `libGL.so` on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libGL.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) gives a few options:

```
libgl1-mesa-dev
fglrx[-updates]
nvidia-*[-updates]
```

Which package you select depends on what hardware you are using. In case you aren't using an AMD or NVidia graphics card, you can install the MESA package:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Comment: libgl1-mesa-dev is already installed and that is the problem... but for  some reason it cannot locate /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so

Comment: @Dave does that file exist? What does `ls -l` for that path say?